# Is there any window management library in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have many browser windows, opened from JavaScript. And I want to manage them - place cascade, tile and resize them all at the same time. Are there any libraries that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know if JavaScript is allowed to access anything besides the window it is currently running in. Just think about the different browser implementations e.g. when a browser always opens a new tab instead of a window (you can't resize and place them), or opens it as a child window inside the application (as Opera does) etc. Just because of that I don't think it is possible in a proper way.

If you really need a more sophisticated JavaScript window manager you might want to take a look at [ExtJS](http://extjs.com). It generally gives you move control over your entire user interface.

Comment: JavaScript can manage windows that it opens (which the author mentioned is being done) programmatically. JavaScript can resize and reposition windows as long as the executing script "owns" the window.

Comment: You actually *can* resize and place new tabs, it just affects the whole window the tab is in.

Comment: Well ok but why isn't there an answer to the actual question yet?

Answer (score 1):

In the past I would have just used the DOM standards documentation to figure out what I can do as a starting place.  www.w3.org/TR/Window/

If you are looking for a simple library that you can use, which will work well across browsers I would take a look at jquery.  http://jqueryui.com/